# Shiny: How do I use the session information from the URL outside a reactive routine

Tags: shiny

I'm trying to subset data for plotting based on parameters in the URL string and do it only once for an entire shiny session.  The data comes from a large database and I don't need to retrieve it over and over again as the use changes the graphic parameters.  Each subsequent plot should be derived from this initial data frame.  I've tried the following only to see the following message: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  URLString <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
  con <- dbConnect(
  RMariaDB::MariaDB(), ....
)
queryString = paste(
"SELECT * FROM Data where UniqueID = '",
URLString['UniqueID'],
sep = ""
)
res <- dbSendQuery(con, queryString)
fetchedRows = data.frame(dbFetch(res))
dbClearResult(res)
dbDisconnect(con)
```

Thanks

Comment: See https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/isolate.html

Comment: Do i wrap the code in an non-specific observe and then isolate the section that references the Session object.  I had assumed that Session was not reactive.  It certainly shouldn't change during the course of a series of responses to changes on the screen.

Comment: Added an example. isolate can be used anywhere. And while the `session` object itself is not reactive, `session$clientData$url_search` is, so you'll still need to use it in a reactive context (or in an isolate block).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  That seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

`session$clientData$url_search` is a reactive value, but you can access it in a non-reactive fashion using [`shiny::isolate()`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/isolate.html).

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$a(href = "?param=123", "?param=123")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  URLString <- parseQueryString(isolate(session$clientData$url_search))
  print(URLString)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```